# How to link to a specific tab on a page | Bootstrap & Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an about page with different tabs that I want to link to individually through my footer. I've checked out other solutions to this but I'm not sure of two things. I've tried to use the following javascript to solve this, but I'm not sure how to configure what is here:

A) How do I configure the JavaScript to work with my HTML?

B) Do I need to duplicate the following JS for each tab on the page?

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('/info#advertise-tab')) {
  $('.nav-tabs li a[href="info' + url.split('#')[1] + 'advertise-tab"]').tab('shown.bs.tab');
}

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs li a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

My page's view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" id="advertise-li"><a href="#advertise-tab" aria-controls="advertise-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Advertise</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" id="legal-li"><a href="#legal-tab" aria-controls="legal-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Legal</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="infoTabContent">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="advertise-tab">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="legal-tab">
    <p>other stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Page footer links:

```
<a href="/info#advertise-tab">Advertise</a>
<a href="/info#legal-tab">Legal</a>
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk2f2x2L/)

Comment: Does the code you've given work with your html? If not - what are you seeing instead? what have you tried to make it work?

Comment: It just goes to the page with the active tab open. Do I need to remove active? I've tested with/without the `li` before `a` and tried multiple combinations of `a[href="` and `"]`

Comment: Have you tried making a fiddle with the code? It'll help us actively play with it to figure out what e can do to fix it :)

Comment: No, I'd rather not use fiddle unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: From our perspective... it's often easier for us to fiddle with it to figure out how to make it work... even if you don't need it yourself ;) But I understand if you don't want to.

Comment: Where I'd start to look is here: `'.nav-tabs li a[href="info' + url.split('#')[1] + 'advertise-tab"]'` - this is looking for a *tab* with an href that starts with `info`... but your tabs don't have that - they're just something like `#advertise-tab` it's only your footer-links that have the full URL.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using `$('.nav-tabs a[href="' + url.split('#')[1] + 'advertise-tab"]').tab('shown.bs.tab');` and it didn't even work with that.

Comment: I've added the fiddle. Thanks for encouraging me to use it, as well as walking through this with me instead of just giving me an answer!

Comment: I've tried something else based on what you said. `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#advertise-tab"]').tab('shown.bs.tab');` This isn't working, nor with `li` before `a`.

Comment: Try doing something other than making it a tab... eg add a really obvious css-class that turns the bg-color red or something. Then once you've got the selector correctly selecting, you can try `tab` on it... because it could be that the `tab` function is expecting a single element, an is reacting weirdly to it returning a set-with-one-element (which a selector on a class invariably and annoyingly returns)... but you can't tell yet what part of your code is failing... so bisecting what you're trying to do helps you narrow that down.